# Unix Command Finding Max Line Value

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I have a text file with a series of floating point numbers – one per line – like so:

```
1
0.98
1.21
0.68
0.647
0.1
```

**More specifically**: I generate these lines using an `awk` call.

How would I go about extracting the largest of these numbers in a single call? Bonus points for extracting the top *n* values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `cat your_filename | sort -n | head -1`

Read about `head` - you can pass number of how many lines you want to display.

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah I thought sort would be involved. Thanks for the head tip! Generally I would use 'tail'

Comment: Head can display top n rows, tail can display bottom n rows, sort can also do in reverse order, so it will also work ;)

Comment: printf '1\n0.98\n1.21\n0.68\n0.647\n0.1\n' | sort | tail -n 1